# How to add a debugging output statement to detect words where numbers should be? (VS2017)

Tags: vba

(Visual Studio 2017)

Basically I have 4 textboxes, I already have these to detect if theres no number put in but how do I make it detect and make a messagebox if words are put in instead? (As the calculation will ignore it if It adds up 1, 2, three, 4, the total will just be 7 instead of 10).

Basically I just want it to tell the user with a messagebox that you can't use words.

If Textbox1.Text = ?? Then
Messagebox.Show("Data was inserted as words not numbers")
EndIF

What should replace the ??

Thanks!

Comment: Visual Studio does not use VBA - that is a language that's linked to an application such as Microsoft Excel. Which programming language are you actually using? If you don't tag correctly you won't get efficient help. Please take a moment to *read* the information the site shows you - about tags and about how to ask questions.

Comment: @CindyMeister 1. I already fixed it myself. 2. VBA is very similar and i have used solutions from VBA that work in VS. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
If Val(TextBox1.Text) <= 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Data was not inserted correctly!")
        End If
```

That fixes it.